# Directus v9: Is there a way to make links and/or buttons in the page view?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, directus

I have a directus 9 project. One table is for contacts.

Contacts have emails and a special button to click which leads to an external site.

Is it possible to directly click the email (as a mailto: link) and also show to button in the page view?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Custom displays](https://docs.directus.io/extensions/displays/). In the component field you'd need to determine if the value is a link and return it as such, possibly with [linkify-string](https://linkify.js.org/docs/linkify-string.html) or regex patterns.

Comment: You're right! Custom displays are the solution for the hrefs. But how to show the custom button which leads to an external website (including an access token and the id of the element)? I think it would be possible with something like a pseudo-field which also has a custom display. But i dont want to hardcode the access token in the extension..

Comment: Still a Custom Display, but you would use the `alias` type, which does not connect to an actual field. Take a look at something like "Button Links" in the core codebase for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks. I made a little repo with some useful display-extensions. Maybe add some more in the future.
https://github.com/lucameusburger/directus-display-extensions